# Stub promises with sinon

Tags: node.js, axios, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I have a Node js controller that sends an external api which I need to stub using Sinon.
When I mocked the resolve, it went as expected but when I try to mock the reject as well, I get an error which I can't understand.

controller:

```
let getDocumentByTemplate = (body) => {
    return new Promise(async (res, rej)=> {
        const accessToken = await getAccessToken()
        const fullName = body.firstname + " " + body.lastname
        const itemId = body.item_id
        const options = {
            url: `${process.env.Url}`,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken.token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: //some data
        }
        axios.post(options.url, options.data, {headers:options.headers}).then((data)=>{
    
           return res(data.data)
        }).catch( (error)=>{
            return rej(error)

        })
    })
```

spec file:

```
 beforeEach(function () {
            this.sandbox.axiosStub = this.sandbox.stub(axios, 'post')
        })
 it('should fail if token invalid', async function () {
            token.token= null
            const getTokenStub = this.sandbox.stub(cache, 'get')
                .callsFake(() => token )

            this.sandbox.axiosStub.callsFake(() => Promise.reject(error))

            const res = await getDocumentByTemplate(body)
            console.log(res)
            this.sandbox.assert.calledOnce(getTokenStub)
            expect(res.code).to.eql(1537)
            expect(res.error).to.eql("invalid_token")

        })
```

as a result of the test, I get:

> ```
>     should fail if token invalid:
>  Error: the object {   "code": 1537   "error": "invalid_token" } was thrown, throw an Error :)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mocked the function properly, but you also need to handle the promise rejection in your test. I recommend to use [chai-as-promised](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) plugin for that:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
```

Then in your test use can expect the promise to be rejected as follows:

```
await expect(getDocumentByTemplate(body)).to.eventually.be.rejected
    .and.to.include({
        code: 1537,
        error: 'invalid_token'
    })
```